# Incorrect user board?

Tags: support, reputation

I just looked at the users tab, and Loren Ipsum only has 750 rep, but she is still at the top... Why is this? None of the users, even the ones that I thought had 10,000+ rep, have more than 750?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the users page look like this?

[image: user tabs]

The page is showing how much reputation each user has gained this month (or maybe in the last month; I'm not sure which).  To see all-time reputation, click on "all".

Comment: Ok! Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks!